# Battery remaining time

Tags: batteries, electricity

I have a non-rechargeable 3.6V, 19Ah lithium polymer battery, and I want to calculate the remaining time for the battery from its measured voltage assuming that the average consumption current is constant.
I've read about the state of charge but don't have a curve for it in the datasheet.
The voltage battery will be measured by a voltage divider.
Any help how to estimate the approximate reaming time?

Comment: Measuring the capacity a battery using the voltage is pretty hard. If you take a look at a curve of the discharge of a Li-Poly you would see that for a large part during discharge the voltage has a pretty flat characteristic. Are you also looking into different ways of calculating the state of charge or the approximate remaining time, by measuring the energy going in and out for example. 
https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/6/7/4/7/9/5112a224ce395fb479000003.png

Comment: We don't have a datasheet (of course) or a battery model, or ACTUAL chemistry , or discharge current or ... If you provide ll the relevant information that YOU have then we can help a lot better. || Tdischarge = mAh/constant_mA at manufacturer's rated mAh at that mA rate.  Vcell MAY be useful depending on chemistry and load. Caoacity in mAh varies with mA .

Comment: A battery number is not remotely "the relevant information" required. It may be all you have, but that means you need to start doing research to find a detailed data sheet. We are not a free R&D service.